At what point does hanging items on the interior side of an exterior wall become a concern regarding damage to the insulation?
Take a large toggle bolt. That can break the vapor barrier and compress the insulation. Or at least that's what I'm thinking. Small anchors should be okay, no?

Maybe getting close to 500.  Large toggles make me think you want to hang something heavy.  If so, think about screwing into studs for better nights sleep.  Punching drywall results in broken drywall.  Punching a stud results in a broken hand.

I used the toggle bolt as an example, and of course studs are better, but it's just something that occurred to me and I wanted to ask about in a general way.

As crip said,  If you are counting attachments in the hundreds, then there may be and issue otherwise it is nothing to worry about.

Most vapour barriers are not perfect.  closer to perfect is nice.  Most insulation can be compressed by .5 to 1 inch all over without losing too much insulation value to matter, so a few toggle bolts/drywall anchors will not matter.

Understood. Thanks.

There are two types of things you should be hanging on a typical drywall over stud wall:

Light stuff

This includes pictures, small mirrors, etc. For these things, there are a variety of anchors, toggle bolts, etc. None of which should really be of much concern for the insulation, vapor barrier, etc.

Heavy stuff

This includes shelves, large mirrors, TVs/TV mounts, cabinets, etc. For these things you should not have any concern about insulation, vapor barrier, etc. because all of your anchors should be screws into studs.
If you need to hang heavy stuff on a wall and can't use the studs, that's when it gets tricky. There are some ways around the problem which are really "use the studs" - e.g., attach plywood to two (or more) studs and attach the heavy items to the plywood. There are some ways which don't use the studs - e.g., really big toggle bolts, but I don't usually recommend them.
